# Hosting multiple applications behind Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx

We're moving to an approach where several app instances are created for multiple use cases. In front of the whole stack, we use Nginx as a reverse proxy.

We define it like this:

```
    location /admin {
        rewrite /admin/(.*) /admin/$1  break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }

    location /client {
        rewrite /client/(.*) /client/$1  break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
```

The problem I have is - any URL normalisation drops the `/app`. So when I browse `https://localhost/admin/page1` all the requests from the front end (including static files) `https://localhost/page1`

What I want to achieve is, when `app` segment is present, all the requests will hit a respective app server. Including static content and websockets requests.

Comment: show pls the full configuration `nginx -T`

Answer (score 0):

It is your application that generates the links to static resources in the HTML code it generates.

Therefore you must configure your application's base URL to match the location in your proxy case.

The `rewrite` statements in your configuration are not needed. They don't actually do anything.